# Changing image size in Markdown

Tags: image, markdown

I just got started with Markdown. I love it, but there is one thing bugging me: How can I change the size of an image using Markdown?

The documentation only gives the following suggestion for an image:

```
![drawing](drawing.jpg)
```

If it is possible I would like the picture to also be centered. I am asking for general Markdown, not just how GitHub does it.

Comment: For top image (like repo logo) I just make a "white padding" in original image before export to PNG.

Comment: You should really fix the accepted answer the to HTML one as the current answer uses non-standard markdown features that don't work broadly

Comment: What is that `!` about?

Comment: @buhtz It is to differentiate a normal HTML link `[text](URL)` from an image `![alt text](image URL)`.

Comment: Note: [GitLab 15.7+, Dec. 2022, officially adopts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74906593/6309) the `![alt text](image URL){width=x height=y}` convention.

Comment: The answer basically is: it is not possible. You have to use html. :(

Comment: I wrote [this simple script](https://gist.github.com/simonbromberg/6781bd9c49691b7fed7185d369d0cff8) (GitHub gist link) for converting the image markdown to HTML. This can be run via Siri Shortcuts, Automator, or whichever service your OS supports. You can attach it to a keyboard shortcut to run it quickly whenever you need to make the conversion on some selected text. Adjust the HTML in the script as needed.

Answer (score 1801, accepted):

You could just use some HTML in your Markdown:

```html
<img src="drawing.jpg" alt="drawing" width="200"/>
```

Or via `style` attribute (**not supported by GitHub**)

```html
<img src="drawing.jpg" alt="drawing" style="width:200px;"/>
```

Or you could use a custom CSS file as described in this answer on *[Markdown and image alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255170/markdown-and-image-alignment#answer-5054055)*

```
![drawing](drawing.jpg)
```

CSS in another file:

```css
img[alt=drawing] { width: 200px; }
```

Comment: Using inline `style` does not work in most websites (e.g. GitHub) site it will get sanitized. Prefer `width` and `height` instead as mentioned by @kushdillip.

Comment: The solution based on the alt attribute is very bad and you shouldn't use it, it breaks **accessibility**.

Comment: The alt in markdown put a caption, the alt in html does something completely different (put text if figure cannot be loaded).

Comment: I was putting an image in a table and it worked better to use `max-width` instead to ensure images are not squished

Comment: Would it be a good idea to recommend a percentage instead of device-dependent pixels? E.g. `<img src="drawing.jpg" alt="drawing" width="50%"/>` ? Tested it on GitHub, it works nicely

Comment: This solution worked for me
 
<img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1400/1*bSLNlG7crv-p-m4LVYYk3Q.png" width="450" height="250">

Comment: Works on GitHub ...`<img src="drawing.jpg" alt="drawing" width="200"/>` , but sadly does not work in the WebStorm/Jetbrains markdown viewer.

Comment: @JulienColomb `alt` is _always_ what's displayed as alternative for when the image can't load OR when the user can't see it. It does exactly the same thing. You're thinking of a separate attribute, `title` which makes hover text. Some browsers, if there's no `title` supplied, will display the alt text in both places. The accessibility complaint is valid.

Answer (score 889):

With certain Markdown implementations (including [Mou](http://25.io/mou/) and [Marked 2](http://marked2app.com/) (only macOS)) you can append `=WIDTHxHEIGHT` after the URL of the graphic file to resize the image. Do not forget the space before the `=`.

```
![](./pic/pic1_50.png =100x20)
```

You can skip the HEIGHT

```
![](./pic/pic1s.png =250x)
```

And Width

```
![](./pic/pic1s.png =x250)
```

Comment: also note that you cannot have a space after the '='. good:"![](./pic/pic1s.png =250x)", bad:"![](./pic/pic1s.png = 250x)"

Comment: Wow, didn't know that this was possible. Is it also documented somewhere?

Comment: how did you find out about it? i couldn't find it in the original documentation...

Comment: Not in the standard, so it doesn't work with every Markdown parser

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with Redcarpet, which I use with Jekyll, so I'd go with HTML, as @Tieme answered. If you end up running your Markdown through a parser that likes the standard, the HTML will stand up.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when you include title text, e.g. `![](image.png =50x50 "Title text")` (same if dimensions are last)

Comment: Does anyone have examples of Markdown parsers this works with?

Comment: doesn't work in Bitbucket wiki as well. it's wrongly converted into the `title` attribute.

Comment: Does not work, but the HTML <img src=http//... width="..." height="..."> works.

Comment: This is not working as I see here 
https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#images

Comment: As this doesn't work, it would be good to down vote and accept the answer with HTML as the best one.

Comment: Does work for external links in the note taking app I use: Laverna

Comment: Works in Azure DevOps wiki

Comment: Works for HackMD (and probably CodiMD I assume)

Comment: Confirmed it does not work with python-markdown parser, or pypandoc parser.

Comment: Hi @prosseek, I tried the solution but it doesn't seem to work. `![image](image.svg =100x200)`

Comment: It doesn't work on Github comments which use markdown feature..

Comment: The answer mentions skipping HEIGHT, but I found out one can also skip WIDTH: `![](./pic/pic1s.png =x200)`

Comment: @underscore_d in my case it was Azure DevOps wiki markdown, which is pretty niche, but I expect it to work in other places.

Comment: How to use this in gatsby?

Comment: Azure Wiki worked like a charm. I used `(___URL =300X)` hence the image got resized proportionally with Width, as the Height was skipped

Comment: Does not work in GitHub MarkDown renderer (on GitHub.com or GitHub Pages), which is a shame, because this looks much better than HTML. Works in Azure DevOps wiki.

Answer (score 501):

The accepted answer here isn't working with any Markdown editor available in the apps I have used till date like Ghost, Stackedit.io or even in the StackOverflow editor. I found a workaround [here in the StackEdit.io issue tracker](https://github.com/benweet/stackedit/issues/164).

The solution is to directly use HTML syntax, and it works perfectly:

```
<img src="http://....jpg" width="200" height="200" />
```

Comment: This worked great for me!  Inline CSS wasn't working with GitHub Markdown but the "old school" height/width attributes worked just fine.

Comment: Good thing is that this one also works if you're trying to use a markdown viewer for local files in a browser extension/add-on.

Comment: Github likes this.

Comment: This is great except not in my ipython notebooks at github.

Comment: Note that on Stack Exchange sites you must use this exact format, and no other attributes (note even `alt`) are seemingly allowed (you may omit `width` or `height`, and the space before `/>` is optional, but other than that no extra whitespace is allowed). GitHub, by contrast, supports (at least) also `alt` and `title` attributes, and allows extra whitespace.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, the simple solution is to link to a different version of the picture. Each image you upload gets rendered in six different versions, which you can switch between by adding a character to indicate the desired size before the `.png` extension. For details, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253403/how-to-reduce-image-size-on-stack-overflow

Comment: This does NOT work for me in Jupyter.  The image just stays the original size. "
The version of the notebook server is: 6.4.6"

Comment: The real aim of Markdown is to avoid HTML to so it can be rendered on many different platforms. To keep things clean, the best option is just to resize the image, this way the markdown will work everywhere

Answer (score 216):

Just use:

```
<img src="Assets/icon.png" width="200">
```

instead of:

```
![](Assets/icon.png)
```

Comment: Most Markdown implementations have a modified syntax for this so you don't need to insert the raw HTML tag, but this is the right thing to do if the implementation you're using doesn't have one.

Comment: This is compatible in github

Comment: Works on Gitlab

Comment: Does not work in Jupyter.

Answer (score 162):

Combining two answers I came out with a solution, that might not look that pretty,
but it works!

It creates a thumbnail with a specific size that might be clicked to bring you to the max resolution image.

```
[<img src="image.png" width="250"/>](image.png)
```

Here's an example! I tested it on Visual Code and Github.
[image: Example markdown]

Thanks to the feedback, we know that this also works on:

- GitLab
- Jupyter Notebook
- StackOverflow

Comment: Excellent. Works with GitLab Enterprise.

Comment: If I have a markdown link: `[myLink]: ./image.png`, how can I apply this solution, to avoid duplicate src ? Example: `[<img src="[myLink]" width="250"/>](image.png)`

Comment: @VictorZanella You simply cannot do that, that's the drawback, but on the other hand you are able to use other image as a cover, so it's a feature! ;)
You always can use some template engine. I've found one for GitHub as an action and I think that It should be convinced enough. variables-in-markdown

Comment: @Lwi I'm happy I could help 

Comment: This works on Github pages using jekyll and Kramdown.

Comment: works with vscode local viewer too

Comment: Complex but precisely what I want. Hope it works with github.

Comment: Nice one! :)
It works in *Obsidian*. I used `style="display: block; margin: auto; "` to even center the image!

Answer (score 137):

If you are writing MarkDown for PanDoc, you can do this:

```
![drawing](drawing.jpg){ width=50% }
```

This adds `style="width: 50%;"` to the HTML `<img>` tag, or `[width=0.5\textwidth]` to `\includegraphics` in LaTeX.

Source: http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-link_attributes

Comment: It is even nicer than specifying size in points directly. I am glad this is the approach Pandoc has chosen!

Comment: @m0z4rt GitHub probably does not use PanDoc to render the MarkDown.

Comment: @rudolfbyker thank you so much. For Mkdocs-material it worked with adding ```-attr_list``` in ```markdown_extensions```` in ```mkdocs.yml```.

Comment: Works for R v. 4.2.0 with `tinytex`!

Comment: Recently Gitlab adopted this format when using rich text editing. @VonC already said it some months ago

Comment: Thanks. I find this the best solution given here: (1) it does not assume use of html, (2) it shows how to define the width by relative size, (3) it is concise. To be perfect, it could also have included how to define the width/height by absolute size.

Comment: This works for GitLab thanks

Comment: This works for Zettlr.

Answer (score 84):

Maybe this has recently changed but the [Kramdown docs](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#links-and-images) show a simple solution.

From the docs

```
Here is an inline ![smiley](smiley.png){:height="36px" width="36px"}.

And here is a referenced ![smile]

[smile]: smile.png
{: height="36px" width="36px"}
```

Works on github with Jekyll and Kramdown.

Comment: May have worked in the past but doesn't work now on Github. Adding an old fashioned <img> tag with width and height still works.

Comment: This is the best solution if you're using Kramdown or Jekyll (which uses Kramdown by default).

Comment: [Block attributes](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/quickref.html#block-attributes) as shown here are a good option with kramdown. The syntax here is slightly wrong, which may be why @piratemurray is having trouble. It should be `{: height=36 width=36}`; this generates HTML attributes, so it should not have the `px` suffix. Alternately, you can use css with `{: style="height:36px; width:36px"}`.

Comment: Works for jekyll! thx. I don't even need height and width, just one is enough. `![alt text](image.png){:height="36px" }`

Comment: I had to make a small change to get this to work properly in Jekyll. This answer as-written outputs malformed HTML, as the `width` and `height` attributes include the "px" part. For me I needed to use `{:height="36" width="36"}`

Comment: As of today, the above code for me if I upload a kramdown file to GitHub Pages and lets Jekyll to translate it to \*.html. The double quotes in `height="36"` *do* matter. See [this commit](https://github.com/vojtech-filipec/vojtech-filipec.github.io/commit/eb617af9d12fde8c8244443bb8c60950016c585d#diff-ba0609637b02c25ea9b4dc0a300c1487), line 11.

Answer (score 51):

Replace `![title](image-url.type)` with `<img src="https://image-url.type" width="200" height="200"/>`

Comment: Works. But using HTML defeats the object of using a **simpler than HTML** markup language.

Comment: It's NOT working for every markdown implementation. You should specify the particular markdown package in your answer. So the down vote

Answer (score 31):

One might draw on the **`alt` attribute** that can be set in almost all Markdown implementations/renderes **together with CSS-selectors** based on attribute values. The advantage is that one can easily define a whole set of different picture sizes (and further attributes).

**Markdown:**

```
![minipic](mypic.jpg)
```

**CSS:**

```
img[alt="minipic"] { 
  max-width:  20px; 
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as [Tieme's earlier answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14747656/477035)?

Comment: This is a misuse of the alt attribute and hurts accessibility.

Comment: Yes, it is a hack BUT still seems to be the only thing that works across Markdown flavors. +1 for pointing that out (people using screen readers get problems with that right? They will get also problems with all those not bothering with using alt the right way).

Answer (score 24):

If you are [using kramdown](http://kramdown.rubyforge.org/syntax.html#block-ials), you can do this:

```css
{:.foo}
![drawing](drawing.jpg)
```

Then add this to [your Custom CSS](http://mouapp.com):

```css
.foo {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: I would recommend against setting the width only in CSS. It is useful to tell the browser how large the image element will be before the image and stylesheet are done loading so that it can optimize the layout of elements around the image without doing a reflow.

Answer (score 21):

Building on from Tiemes answer, if you're using [CSS 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets#CSS_3) you can use a [substring selector](http://www.css3.info/preview/attribute-selectors/):

This selector will match any image with an alt tag that ends with '-fullwidth':

```
img[alt$="-fullwidth"]{
  width:  100%;
  display: block;
}
```

Then you can still use the alt tag for its [intended purpose](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/altAttribute) to describe the image.

The Markdown for the above could be something like:

```
![Picture of the Beach -fullwidth](beach.jpg)
```

I've been using this in Ghost markdown, and it has been working well.

Comment: Works perfectly on kramdown+jekyll-3.1.2 as well.

Comment: If you don't need to render the image at full width, it's better to put the pixel size directly on the tag (not with CSS).

Answer (score 21):

If you are using [reference style](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#images) images in *GitHub Flavored Markdown*:

```
Here is an image of tree: 
![alt text][tree]{height=400px width=500px}


[//]: # (Image References)
[tree]: ./images/tree.png "This is a tree"
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. The reference linked mentions nothing about height/width

Comment: @ShubhamChaudhary  The referenced link shows "what is a _reference style image_" in _[Github Flavored Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown#GitHub_Flavored_Markdown_(GFM))_. Maybe you don't have a reference style image or are using another variant of Markdown.

Comment: Oh, you linked it to explain 'reference style'. In context of the answer, the link doesn't mention anything about the height/width syntax `{height=100px width=100px}`

Answer (score 17):

For those intereseted in an `rmarkdown` and `knitr` solution. There are some ways to resize images in an `.rmd` file without the use of `html`:

You can simply specify a width for an image by adding `{width=123px}`. Don't introduce whitespace in between the brackets:

```
![image description]('your-image.png'){width=250px}
```

Another option is to use `knitr::include_graphics`:

````
```{r, fig.cap="image description", out.width = '50%'}
knitr::include_graphics('your-image.png')
```
````

Comment: How can I change both height and width? For the first option specifically. I tried putting height and width in the same `{}` but failed. Separate `{}`s fail too.

Comment: @NelsonGon: I never needed to specify both, since the height also scales, when width is specified. Therefore I don't know whether that would be possible and how to achieve it. Good question, though..

Comment: Thanks, I since figured I can do it like so: `{height=x width=y}`. It seems this syntax does not recognize commas but I could specify other attributes including style elements.

Answer (score 16):

If you have one image in each md file, one handy way to control image size is:

adding css style as follows:

```
## Who Invented JSON?
`Douglas Crockford`

Douglas Crockford originally specified the JSON format in the early 2000s.
![Douglas Crockford](img/Douglas_Crockford.jpg)

<style type="text/css">
    img {
        width: 250px;
    }
</style>
```

and the output will be like:
[image]

If you have more images in each md page, then the handy way to control each image or each customized tag is to define each element in css. For this case for the img tag we could have:

```css
//in css or within style tags:
    img[alt="Result1"] {
    width: 100px;
    }

    img[alt="Result2"] {
    width: 200px;
    }
    img[alt="Result3"] {
    width: 400px;
    }

// try in md one of the methods shown below to insert image in your document:
```

```html
 <br/>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUb54.png" alt="Result1"> <br/>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUb54.png" alt="Result2"> <br/>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUb54.png" alt="Result3"> <br/>

<br/>

in md:<br/>
![Result1](img/res-img-1.png) <br/>

![Result2](img/res-img-2.png) <br/>

![Result3](img/res-img-3.png)
```

Answer (score 16):

Not a universal solution, but if you're working in [Obsidian](https://obsidian.md/) it has its own syntax for this:

```markdown
![Engelbart|100x145](https://history-computer.com/ModernComputer/Basis/images/Engelbart.jpg)
```

Or, to use the example from the question:

```markdown
![drawing|200x100](drawing.jpg)
```

From: [Basic formatting syntax - Obsidian Help](https://help.obsidian.md/Editing+and+formatting/Basic+formatting+syntax)

Comment: Nice. But that's not a universal solution.

Comment: As @Martin has pointed out this isn't a universal solution, but since it's a solution to a common version of this problem I think it's still worth having here.

Answer (score 15):

I came here searching for an answer. Some awesome suggestions here. And gold information pointing out that markdown supports HTMl completely!

A good clean solution is always to go with pure html syntax for sure. With the  tag.

But I was trying to still stick to the markdown syntax so I tried wrapping it around a  tag and added whatever attributes i wanted for the image inside the div tag. And it WORKS!!

```
<div style="width:50%">![Chilling](https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/fjords.jpg)</div>
```

So this way external images are supported!

Just thought I would put this out there as it isn't in any of the answers. :)

Comment: You cant put markdown inside of HTML, you will need to replace `![chilling](link)` with `<img src="link" alt="chilling">`.

Answer (score 15):

For all looking for solutions which work in **R markdown/ bookdown**, these of the previous solutions do/do not work or need slight adaption:

#### Working

- Append `{ width=50% }` or `{ width=50% height=50% }`

  - `![foo](foo.png){ width=50% }`
  - `![foo](foo.png){ width=50% height=50% }`
  - **Important:** no comma between width and height – i.e. `{ width=50%, height=30% }` ***won't work***!
- Append `{ height="36px" width="36px" }`

  - `![foo](foo.png){ height="36px" width="36px" }`
  - **Note:** `{:height="36px" width="36px"}` with colon, as from @sayth, seems not to work with R markdown

#### Not working:

- Append `=WIDTHxHEIGHT`

  - after the URL of the graphic file to resize the image (as from @prosseek)
  - neither `=WIDTHxHEIGHT` `![foo](foo.png =100x20)` nor `=WIDTH` only `![foo](foo.png =250x)` work

Answer (score 15):

This one works for me it's not in one line but i hope it works for you.

```
<div>
<img src="attachment:image.png" width="500" height="300"/>
</div>
```

Comment: `<div><img src="attachment:image.png" width="500" height="300"/></div>` <- one line :D

Answer (score 13):

You could use this one as well with kramdown:

```
markdown
![drawing](drawing.jpg)   
{:.some-css-class style="width: 200px"}
```

or

```
markdown
![drawing](drawing.jpg)   
{:.some-css-class width="200"}
```

This way you can directly add arbitrary attributes to the last html element. To add classes there is a shortcut **.class.secondclass**.

Answer (score 13):

I know that this answer is a bit specific, but it might help others in need.

As many photos are uploaded using the [Imgur service](https://imgur.com), you can use [the API detailed here](https://api.imgur.com/models/image#thumbs) to change the size of the photo.

When uploading a photo in a GitHub issue comment, it will be added through Imgur, so this will help a lot if the photo is very big.

Basically, instead of https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y682Q.gif, you would put [http://i.imgur.com/12345m.jpg](https://i.imgur.com/12345m.jpg) for medium sized image.

Comment: Stack Overflow has a similar facility; see the comment I left on another answer for a link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14675913/changing-image-size-in-markdown#comment114230318_21972032

Answer (score 12):

I scripted the simple tag parser for using a custom-size img tag in [Jekyll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jekyll_%28software%29).

https://gist.github.com/nurinamu/4ccf7197a1bdfb0d7079

```
{% img /path/to/img.png 100x200 %}
```

You can add the file to the `_plugins` folder.

Answer (score 12):

For those using Markdown on Google Colaboratory, there is no need to have the image uploaded to the session storage folder, or linked on Google Drive. If the image has a URL, and it can be included on the Jupyter notebook, and its size changed as follows:

```
<img src="https://image.png" width="500" height="500" />
```

[image]

Note that entering just the `width` leaving the `height` completely out allows the image to adjust to small screens (i.e. phone).

Comment: Works. But using HTML defeats the object of using a **simpler than HTML** markup language.

Answer (score 9):

## Resizing Markdown Image Attachments in Jupyter Notebook

*I'm using `jupyter_core-4.4.0` & jupyter notebook.*

#### If you're attaching your images by inserting them into the markdown like this:

```
![Screen%20Shot%202019-08-06%20at%201.48.10%20PM.png](attachment:Screen%20Shot%202019-08-06%20at%201.48.10%20PM.png)
```

#### These `attachment` links **don't** work:

```
<img src="attachment:Screen%20Shot%202019-08-06%20at%201.48.10%20PM.png" width="500"/>
```

#### **DO THIS**. This **does** work.

Just add div brackets.

```
<div>
<img src="attachment:Screen%20Shot%202019-08-06%20at%201.48.10%20PM.png" width="500"/>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: THE BEST ANSWER!

Comment: In a sea of answers, I thought no one would address this specific case, but MrFun for the win!

Answer (score 8):

For R-Markdown, neither of the above solutions worked for me, so I turned to regular [LaTeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) syntax, which works just fine.

```
\begin{figure}
 \includegraphics[width=300pt, height = 125 pt]{drawing.jpg}
\end{figure}
```

Then you can use e.g. the `\begin{center}` statement to center the image.

Comment: +1, but better just `\centering` after `\begin{figure}` or  nothing, if you use ` \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{drawing.jpg}` that I think that should be the default pandoc output at least when the image is wider that the text.

Answer (score 6):

When using [Flask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flask_%28web_framework%29) (I am using it with flat pages)... I found that enabling explicitly (was not by default for some reason) 'attr_list' in extensions within the call to markdown does the trick - and then one can use the attributes (very useful also to access CSS - class="my class" for example...).

FLATPAGES_HTML_RENDERER = prerender_jinja

and the function:

```
def prerender_jinja(text):
    prerendered_body = render_template_string(Markup(text))
    pygmented_body   = markdown.markdown(prerendered_body, extensions=['codehilite', 'fenced_code', 'tables', 'attr_list'])
    return pygmented_body
```

And then in Markdown:

```
![image](https://octodex.github.com/images/yaktocat.png "This is a tooltip"){: width=200px}
```

Answer (score 6):

## There is way with add class and css style

`![pic][logo]{.classname}`

### then write down link and css below

```
[logo]: (picurl)

<style type="text/css">
    .classname{
        width: 200px;
    }
</style>
```

[Reference Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255170/markdown-and-image-alignment)

Answer (score 6):

The addition of relative dimensions to the source URL will be rendered in the majority of Markdown renderers.

We implemented this in [Corilla](http://www.corilla.com) as I think the pattern is one that follows expectations of existing workflows without pushing the user to rely on basic HTML. If your favourite tool doesn't follow a similar pattern it's worth raising a feature request.

**Example of syntax:**

`![a-kitten.jpg](//corilla.com/a-kitten-2xU3C2.jpg =200x200)`

**Example of kitten:**

[image: kitten]

Comment: A shame that it doesn't work on GitHub at present, but I'd suggest raising a feature request all the same.

Answer (score 6):

For future reference:

Markdown implementation for [Joplin](https://joplinapp.org) allows controlling the size of imported images in the following manner:

`<img src=":/7653a812439451eb1803236687a70ca" width="450"/>`

This feature was  requested [here](https://discourse.joplinapp.org/t/resize-images/708) and as [promised](https://discourse.joplinapp.org/t/resize-images/708/5) by [Laurent](https://github.com/laurent22) this has been implemented.

It took me a while to figure the Joplin specific answer.

Answer (score 6):

Via plain backward compatible MD:

```
![<alt>](<imguri>#<w>x<h> "<title>")
```

where w, h defines the bounding box to aspect fit into, as eg in Flutter package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_markdown

Code: https://github.com/flutter/packages/blob/9e8f5227ac14026c419f481ed1dfcb7b53961475/packages/flutter_markdown/lib/src/builder.dart#L473

Reconsider html workarounds breaking compatibility as people might use native/non-html components/apps to display markdown.

Answer (score 6):

Put the image URL in  tag below. Remember to change the width and height accordingly.
Like This

```
<img src="IMAGE_URL_HERE"  width="300" height="300">
```

You can specify width without height attribute and vice versa.

Alternatively, you can change image size using percentage value like below:

```
<img src="IMAGE_URL_HERE"  width=50% height=50%>
```

Answer (score 4):

The sheer **<img ... width="50%">** said above, did work on my Github **Readme.md** document.

However my real issue was, that **the image was inside a table cell**, just compressing the text in the beside cell. So the other way was to set columns width in Markdown tables, but the solutions did not really seem enough *markdownish* for my morning.

At last I solved both problems by simply forcing the beside text cell with as much **"& nbsp;"** as I needed.

I hope this helps. Bye and thanks everybody.

Answer (score 3):

If we just use normal HTML image tag like this it is working, if you use bootstrap for styling. I use this in website made with Jekyll.

```
<img class="img-fluid" src="./img/face.jpg" alt="img-verification">
```

If we add bootstrap classes as per this example it works fine.

Comment: The another way to change image size in markdown file is like this `<img src="./assets/app-screenshot.png" alt="app-screen" width="300" />`. Just add width to the image tag.

Answer (score 2):

If changing the initial markdown is not an option for you, this hack might work:

```
newHtml = oldHtml.replace(/<img/g, '<img height="100"');
```

I used this to be able to resize images before sending them in an email (as Outlook ignores any image css styling)

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
<style>
img{width: 50%;}
#foo {color: red;}
</style>

<p id="foo">foo</p>

<p style="color: blue">bar</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using markdown-it, first you need to enable HTML render:

```
const md = require("markdown-it")({
  html: true,
});
```

then you can use in your `.md` file:

```
<img src="" alt="drawing" width="100%" height="200"/>
```

Comment: I think the OP was asking for a **universal** solution.

Answer (score 1):

Well, some of us do not like warnings. Those warnings come from Markdown linting.
So there are two things you need to do:

1. **Use in-line html**:

- Instead of using:
  `![drawing](drawing.jpg)`
- use:
  `<img src="Assets/icon.png" width=250 height=200>`
- 250 and 200 being the preferred width and height of your image, respectively! You can choose to use only one attribute and ignore the other.

2. **Bring down the warnings:**

- At the root of your project, create a `.markdownlint.json` file with the following contents:

```
{
    "MD033": false,
    "MD013": false
}
```

To suppress the warnings. Add other warnings you'd like to suppress here!

Answer (score 0):

Tieme's answer is best for most cases.

In my case, I am using pandoc to convert markdown to latex.  HTML tags won't work here.

My solution is to re-implement `\includegraphics`

```
\let\maxincludegraphics\includegraphics
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[1]{\maxincludegraphics[max width=\textwidth]{#1}}
```

The is analogous to using CSS after a conversion to HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I would just edit the image in some image editor - enlarge the image horizontally, therefore it will get smaller vertically when resized by the renderer to the width of the page.

So, just add some transparent left and right margins.

Answer (score -6):

You can set size at the end of the image like this:

```
![image.png](source **=600x400**)
```

Comment: This looks like a URL query parameter, and won't work for a local file