# Resize image in the wiki of GitHub using Markdown

Tags: html, github, markdown, wiki

I'm writing a wiki page on GitHub, and I'm using Markdown.

My problem is that I'm putting a large image (this image is in its own repository) and I need resize it.

I have tried different solutions, but they do not work:

```markdown
![image](http://url.to/image.png "Title" {width=40px height=400px})

![image](http://url.to/image.png = 250x250)

![image](http://url.to/image.png = 250x)

[[http://url.to/image.png = 250x]]
```

Is there a way to get it?

It is preferable without HTML.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change image size Markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14675913/how-to-change-image-size-markdown)

Answer (score 595, accepted):

### Updated:

Markdown syntax for images (external/internal):

```markdown
![test](https://github.com/favicon.ico)
```

HTML code for *sizing* images (internal/external):

```
<img src="https://github.com/favicon.ico" width="48">
```

Example:

[image: test]

---

### Old Answer:

This should work:

<strike>[[ http://url.to/image.png | height = 100px ]]</strike>

Source: https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/

Comment: Thanks. `<img src="..." width="48">` works in READMEs for images uploaded to GitHub.

Comment: @SamDutton: It seems to work fine also for images hosted elsewhere.

Comment: Test it today. Github won't recognize the syntax of [](..  =400) or [](... =400px), so if I need to resize the picture, I have to use the <img/> syntax.

Comment: what about a gift

Comment: When you replace the markdown syntax with the html, you don't see the correct size in the Github preview. But it does work :)

Comment: The crossed out answer works if the image is added to the wiki itself.

Comment: What @Eduardo said... The 'Old Answer' that you have crossed out is what I have been scouring the internet for—still works great for relative paths (assets inside the wiki). Additionally, I had to add one or two images inside of a table. The pipe character was giving me grief because of typical table formatting in markdown. Escaping the pipe inside a table cell is still valid: `[[ http://url.to/img.png \| height=48px]]`.

Comment: I wrote [this script](https://gist.github.com/simonbromberg/6781bd9c49691b7fed7185d369d0cff8) which can be added to Automator using a Javascript quick action and then with a keyboard shortcut you can quickly convert the automatically generated Github image markdown with the HTML for easy resizing while the text is selected. I would also recommend [submitting feedback to Github](https://support.github.com/contact/feedback) to get them to simplify this.

Comment: The question clearly asks to resize image using Markdown, so could you provide a method to do it in this way. I searched around internet, but no concrete answer.
I don't think this should be an accepted answer.

Answer (score 94):

On GitHub, you can use HTML directly instead of Markdown:

```
<a href="url"><img src="http://url.to/image.png" align="left" height="48" width="48" ></a>
```

This should make it.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, is it possible without html code?

Comment: Just want to note that you can exclude the `width` so that it can scale the width based on height automatically.

Comment: Not just on Github; I believe inline HTML is allowed within Markdown in general...

Answer (score 39):

**Resize by Percentage `width=50% height=50%`**. Example:

```
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZWnhY9T.png" width=50% height=50%>
```

**Resize by Pixels `width="150" height="280"`**. Example:

```
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZWnhY9T.png" width="150" height="280">
```

#### Some tips

- To get a githubusercontent link for an image, drag and drop the image into any issue, and copy/paste the url from the code that is automatically generated. Example code: `![image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/16319829/81180309-2b51f000-8fee-11ea-8a78-ddfe8c3412a7.png)`
- There is [**no way** to change the size of an image if the markdown format is of the form `[]()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62908160/5783745) - so stop looking right now! - you **must** use `<img>` instead
- Another useful summary of conventions that do and don't work [here](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/2554#issuecomment-158936360)
- All of the above is from [here](https://gist.github.com/stevecondylios/dcadb4fc73e63f27a3bbcf17e52058bf)

Comment: This is also a great TIP.

Answer (score 13):

Almost 5 years after only the direct HTML formatting works for images on GitHub and other markdown options still prevent images from loading when specifying some custom sizes even with the wrong dimensions.
I prefer to specify the desired width and get the height calculated automatically, for example,

```html
<img src="https://github.com/your_image.png" alt="Your image title" width="250"/>
```

Answer (score 12):

I have used methods described above. Now I am using the method which is a way similiar but more simple to me.

1. First create add README.md file to your project.
2. Then upload screenshoots or whatever description images needed to your project main directory.
3. After uploading image Assets use html to refer these assets directly without using link like below

Like this:

```
<img src="icon.jpg" width="324" height="324">

<p align="center">
  <img src="screen1.png" width="256" height="455">
  <img src="screen2.png" width="256" height="455">
  <img src="screen3.png" width="256" height="455">
</p>
```

On above example I have used paragraph to align images side by side. If you are going to use single image just use the code as below

```
<img src="icon.jpg" width="324" height="324">
```

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 3):

You can tried to put the image into table of markdown, like this:

```
| ![Kiku](docs/snapshot/home.jpeg)        | ![Kiku](docs/snapshot/sub.jpeg) |
| --------------------------------------- | --------------------------------------- |
| ![Kiku](docs/snapshot/user-center.jpeg) |                                         |
```

it will make the image layout like grid, but it could not custom for each single image size.

Comment: This is great; it will maintain the resolutions while resizing the photos.

Answer (score 1):

GitHub *Pages* now uses *kramdown* as its markdown engine so you can use the following syntax:

```
Here is an inline ![smiley](smiley.png){:height="36px" width="36px"}.
```

http://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#images

I haven't tested it on GitHub wiki though.

Comment: @nicobo I tried seems it doesn't work for external image ?

Comment: This works in GitHib pages using Jekyll, FYI (I realize this isn't precisely the OPs question)

Answer (score -2):

This addresses the different question, how to get images in gist (as opposed to github) markdown in the first place ?

---

In December 2015, it seems that only links to files on
`github.com` or `cloud.githubusercontent.com` or the like work.
Steps that worked for me in a gist:

1. Make a gist, say `Mygist.md` (and optionally more files)
2. Go to the "Write Comment" box at the end
3. Click "Attach files ... by selecting them"; select your local image file
4. GitHub echos a long long string where it put the image, e.g.
   ![khan-lasso-squared](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/1280390/12011119/596fdca4-acc2-11e5-84d0-4878164e04bb.png)
5. Cut-paste that by hand into your `Mygist.md`.

But: GitHub people may change this behavior tomorrow, without documenting it.

Comment: Where is the resize aspect?