# Specify image size in GitHub markdown using ems (or other unit)

Tags: image, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I've seen that it's possible to [specify the image size using pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24383700/resize-image-in-the-wiki-of-github-using-markdown), but pixels isn't a great way to specify image size. I've tried

```
<img src="myimg.png" style="width:20em" />
```

but that didn't work (although [Markdown Viewer for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/markdown-viewer/ckkdlimhmcjmikdlpkmbgfkaikojcbjk) rendered it)

Is it even possible to specify the size with another size unit other than pixels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you need to define `width` and/or `height` attributes to define an image's size, and those attributes only support pixel units. GitHub does no support using the `style` attribute.

As documented in the [github/markup](https://github.com/github/markup#github-markup) project:

> This library is the first step of a journey that every markup file in
>   a repository goes on before it is rendered on GitHub.com:
>
> 1. This library converts the raw markup to HTML. See the list of [supported markup formats](https://github.com/github/markup#markups)
>      below.
> 2. The HTML is sanitized, aggressively removing things that could harm you and your kin—such as `script` tags, inline-styles, and `class` or
>      `id` attributes. See the [sanitization
>      filter](https://github.com/jch/html-pipeline/blob/master/lib/html/pipeline/sanitization_filter.rb)
>      for the full whitelist.
> 3. Syntax highlighting is performed on code blocks. See [github/linguist](https://github.com/github/linguist#syntax-highlighting)
>      for more information about syntax highlighting.
> 4. The HTML is passed through other filters in the [html-pipeline](https://github.com/jch/html-pipeline) that add special
>      sauce, such as
>      [emoji](https://github.com/jch/html-pipeline/blob/master/lib/html/pipeline/emoji_filter.rb),
>      [task
>      lists](https://github.com/github/task_list/blob/master/lib/task_list/filter.rb),
>      [named
>      anchors](https://github.com/jch/html-pipeline/blob/master/lib/html/pipeline/toc_filter.rb),
>      [CDN caching for
>      images](https://github.com/jch/html-pipeline/blob/master/lib/html/pipeline/camo_filter.rb),
>      and 
>      [autolinking](https://github.com/jch/html-pipeline/blob/master/lib/html/pipeline/autolink_filter.rb).
> 5. The resulting HTML is rendered on GitHub.com.

Of note is step 2. Specifically `style` tags are stripped from any user provided content on GitHub's website. However, a review of the sanitation filter indicates that [height](https://github.com/jch/html-pipeline/blob/master/lib/html/pipeline/sanitization_filter.rb#L64) and [width](https://github.com/jch/html-pipeline/blob/master/lib/html/pipeline/sanitization_filter.rb#L73) attributes are whitelisted and not stripped. Note that `width` and `height` attributes can only use pixels as units. Therefore, you cannot us any other type of units to define an image size. Your `img` tag may look like this:

```
<img src="myimg.png" width="20" />
```

Of course, you'll need to adjust the actual size to your desired value.