# Resizing gif in markdown (github)

Tags: markdown

I am trying to resize my gif that is to be displayed in Github. The gif is in a folder in the repository. I have tried a lot of the solutions but they do not work.

[Changing image size in Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14675913/changing-image-size-in-markdown)

```
![Alt Text](/images/output/video1.gif =250x250)
```

[Resize image in the wiki of GitHub using Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24383700/resize-image-in-the-wiki-of-github-using-markdown)

```
<img src="https://github.com/asd/privategithubrepo/images/output/video1.gif" width="48">
```

Comment: Have you checked the HTML using your browsers "view source" or "inspect" tool? Using the cited solutions, what HTML are you seeing for the `img` tag?

Comment: Note that, as explained in [github/markup](https://github.com/github/markup), a sanitation filter is run on the output of the Markdown parser which strips various things. Interestingly, 3 months ago, they [removed the link](https://github.com/github/markup/commit/56a58500418779ee3e06db2bfcd86654acbf2ce7) to the [sanitizer](https://github.com/jch/html-pipeline/blob/master/lib/html/pipeline/sanitization_filter.rb) without any explanation. That sanitation filter included `width` and `height` in the whitelist of approved attributes, but if they are using a different filter now...

Answer (score 32):

you can use HTML syntax for this purpose

```
<img src="/images/output/video1.gif" width="250" height="250"/>
```

I think this will work.

Comment: Note that it's also possible to specify the `height` and `width` as percentage values, e.g. `width="50%"`.