# Change size of image in github flavored markdown without using HTML img tag?

Tags: github, github-flavored-markdown

I am limited to using `[]()` syntax to render an image (as opposed to `<img>`) (the reason for this limitation is because it's currently being used as a workaround for a known bug).

Is there a way to resize an image using ***only*** `[]()` convention (not using `<img>`)?

I have tried some things so far that haven't worked. Most notably:

Adding `?s=200`/`&s=200` parameter to the end of the image url (recommended [here](https://gist.github.com/uupaa/f77d2bcf4dc7a294d109#gistcomment-2180065))

The best solution I have so far is to download the image and resize it and re-upload it. Any way of changing its size from the `md` itself or by way of changing the url (e.g. via a parameter etc) would be much better

Comment: No, there is no way to do this.

Comment: I'm 99% sure about this, but I don't have a reference. I'll leave it as a comment in case somebody else can provide a better one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [GFM (GitHub Flavored Markdown)](https://github.github.com/gfm/#images) specification for images does not include any size attributes.

Meaning a `[]()` won't include any size element in its HTML generated form.

If you [change the Markdown processor to Kramdown](https://docs.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/setting-a-markdown-processor-for-your-github-pages-site-using-jekyll) for GitHub pages, *then* [this would work](https://gist.github.com/uupaa/f77d2bcf4dc7a294d109#gistcomment-2096178):

```
![test image size](/img/post-bg-2015.jpg){:class="img-responsive"}
![test image size](/img/post-bg-2015.jpg){:height="50%" width="50%"}
![test image size](/img/post-bg-2015.jpg){:height="700px" width="400px"}
```

Using HTML would work (provided you use the https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ of your image, but this is not possible in your case.

```
<img src="https://your-image-url.type" width="100" height="100">
```

You can try, for testing:

```
{:refdef: style="width: 10px; height: 10px"}
[![Octocat](https://github.githubassets.com/images/icons/emoji/octocat.png)](./somelink)
{: refdef}
```