# Resizing images in RMarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm trying to convert a R markdown `.Rmd` document to `.pdf`. Unfortunately, the images are too large.  Is there any way to change the size of the image? I Can't use html, this is markdown to pdf.

Comment: Check whether this is helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14675913/how-to-change-image-size-markdown

Answer (score 13):

Use this at the beginning of a chunk:

Decimals assigned to `fig.height` and `fig.width` are interpreted as inches.  Other units of measure also allowed if explicit.

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, fig.height=2.7, fig.width=9}
#your R code here
```
````

Answer (score 5):

I found a comfortable solution by the combination of `fig.height`, `fig.width`, `dpi` and `out.width`.

You can set global parameters at the top by:

`knitr::opts_chunk$set(out.width="400px", dpi=120)`

You can overwrite these properties in any chunk, just set the parameters you need.

`dpi` increases the quality image, so you have to adjust by the other parameters.

`out.width` adjust the size once the image is created.

Decreasing values in `fig.height` and `fig.width` will cause the text/numbers to be bigger (same as reducing image window in Rstudio)

Comment: In my experience, changing fig.height and fig.width will NOT cause the text or numbers to have a changed size.

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple way to resize Images and still being able to add Captions. Use the following syntax within your RMarkdown code and place the Image's Caption beneath the Image:

```
<!-- Einbinden von Bildern in RMarkdown -->
\begin{figure}
\centerline{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{your_image_name.png}}
\caption{Entitäten zur Persistierung der Special Notifications}
\end{figure}
```

To scale the image just adapt the width-value from 0.5 to some other percentage-value fitting your needs.

If you don't want to center the images, just remove the \centerline - Command with it's opening and closing brackets {}.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge `rmarkdown` html formats come with Bootstrap. I add the `img-responsive` with some javascript (at the bottom of my document).

```
<script>
  var d = document.document.getElementsByTagName("img");
  d.className += " img-responsive";
</script>
```