# How do I resize an image on markdown?

Tags: image, rstudio, size, markdown, r-markdown

I imported an image that I made in matlab into markdown in rstudio by using:

```
![figure description here \label{fig:fig1}](../images/static/imageFile.png)
```

However, I looked online and could only find either switching to html `<img src="icon.png" width="200">` which doesn't show up on my pdf file, or appending the width and height to the end:

```
![figure description here \label{fig:fig1}](../images/static/imageFile.png){width=250px}
```

Just adds the caption of {width=250px} to the end of my image.

Is there any other way I can change the size of the image?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resizing images in RMarkdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26881866/resizing-images-in-rmarkdown)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to use `knitr::include_graphics()` and adjust the size using the chunk option `out.width`. The `dpi` setting would also change the size of the image in html output. See [here](https://yihui.org/knitr/options/) for more details on the chunk options.

````
```{r, out.width = '250px'}
knitr::include_graphics('imageFile.png')
```
````

You can also set these options globally if you want to with this code at the top of the script.

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(out.width="250px")
```

Answer (score 4):

Pandoc supports [image dimensions](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-link_attributes):

```
![figure description](imageFile.png){width=250}
```

Make sure you're using a recent pandoc version.

Comment: I'm trying to do this in rstudio markdown and not pandoc. The document doesn't even compile when I add that in markdown.

Comment: rstudio is using pandoc under the hood... but you need a recent version..

Answer (score 0):

Jekyll markdown syntax for image size:

```
![alt](image.png){: width="50%"}
```

or

```
![alt](image.png){: width="50%"}
```