# how to set image size in Hallo.js Markdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, markdown, hallo-js

I am using [hallo.js](http://hallojs.org/) ([Git](https://github.com/bergie/hallo)) for `markdown` editor. I would like to set image width and height.

I already reference [How to change image size markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14675913/how-to-change-image-size-markdown). it is not work in `hallo.js` as below.

Example

```
![](image URL =100x20)
![](image URL |width=100)
```

Comment: `<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" width="100" height="200">`

Comment: The linked question already answers this. If you notice the [highest rated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14747656/866026) is **not** the accepted answer. And the accepted answer acknowledges that it only works in *some* Markdown implementations. It is a non-standard feature. If it doesn't work for you, then use the suggestions for standard Markdown in the highest rated answer.

Comment: Actually, the best answer would be [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21972032/866026). That will work everywhere.

Comment: @Waylan I saw your highest rated answer. it is build in tag of HTML.. it is only way to work for me.