# Resize the image in jupyter notebook using markdown

Tags: html, image, jupyter-notebook, markdown, jupyter

I want to add the image in the Jupyter notebook and I want to have particular height and width. 
When I try to add the image using

> `![](img.png)`

the code is adding the complete image but as per the image dimension and I don't have control over it.
I try to use **![](img.png =200x100)** but then the image does not appear.

Does anybody know of a way to add an image with pre-specified dimensions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change image size Markdown?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14675913/how-to-change-image-size-markdown)

Comment: In the future if you use ![alt] you will see "alt" appear and you know it is working, but that something in your link did not work.

Answer (score 123):

If you're attaching your images by inserting them into the markdown like this:

```markdown
![Screenshot.png](attachment:Screenshot.png)
```

Do this instead:

```
<div>
<img src="attachment:Screenshot.png" width="500"/>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work without the surrounding divs:

```
// this does not work
<img src="attachment:Screenshot.png" width="500"/>
```

PS *I'm using `jupyter_core-4.4.0` & jupyter notebook.*

Comment: This should be the right answer, it works also with google colab using an url in the src tag

Comment: Strange, it doesn't work for me, its simply giving blank. For some reason I guess its not loading the attachment. (I'm using the latest version of Jupyter notebook and python btw

Comment: What I've found in Jupyter is that width DOES work but height DOES NOT.

Comment: Works for me, no need for `attachment:` and works without div

Answer (score 86):

You can use html directly

```
<img src="image.JPG" alt="Drawing" style="width: 200px;"/>
```

Comment: I think this is the correct approach. Unfortunately [block attributes](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/quickref.html#block-attributes) (`{: width=200}`) are not supported by jupyter's markdown renderer.

Comment: Great answer! Is is possible to set the height and width at the same time?

Comment: @edesz: yes: for example, use ``style="width: 400px; height: 300px;" `` in Mark's answer above

Comment: you can also use a percentage value for image width <img src="2D_affine_transformation_matrix.svg" width="90%"/>

Answer (score 61):

Image control in Jupyter markdown is possible but the image needs to be preceded by "attachment" or it doesn't display.

```
<img src="attachment:image.png" width="400">
```

[Cf. Simon Byrne.](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1885)

With a url it works directly:

```
<img src=https://image.slidesharecdn.com/tensorflowppt-160408142819/95/tensorflow-4-638.jpg?cb=1460125744 width="500">
```

Comment: In Jupyter Lab I had success resizing with `width=200` but not the `style="width: 200px;"`.

Comment: The problem is that attachments are no longer recognized and exported to html, reveal, etc. when this syntax is used.

Comment: Note that at least for me, I **first** have to paste by keystroke into a Markdown cell to create the `![](img.png)` syntax, _then_ replace that with the above. Otherwise, it can't seem to find the attachment source image (`attachment:image.png`).

Comment: Currently this works in colab, while the body of the answer doesnt.  <img src="https://image.slidesharecdn.com/tensorflowppt-160408142819/95/tensorflow-4-638.jpg?cb=1460125744" width="500px"/>

Answer (score 12):

You can also use `Image` module from `IPython.display`

https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.Image

for example

```py
from IPython.display import Image
Image(url='https://www.maxpierini.it/ncov/pics/ITA.png', width=200)
```

Use `filename=` instead of `url=` if the image is a local file.

Comment: In contrast to html-tags this solution is preferable, as it allows to export the notebook to pdf (via latex) keeping the resized images.

Answer (score 9):

You need to use HTML as Mark showed you, since you cannot do it with `![](img.png)` syntax. From [John Gruber's website](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#img):

> As of this writing, Markdown has no syntax for specifying the dimensions of an image; if this is important to you, you can simply use regular HTML  tags.

Answer (score 3):

On Python 3.11, MacOS 14.0, this works in a markdown cell:

```
<img src="Screenshot.png" width="500"/>
```

But this doesn't:

```
<div>
<img src="attachment:Screenshot.png" width="500"/>
</div>
```

Versions used:

```
$ pip list|grep jupyter
jupyter                  1.0.0
jupyter_client           8.2.0
jupyter-console          6.6.3
jupyter_core             5.3.0
jupyter-events           0.6.3
jupyter_server           2.5.0
jupyter_server_terminals 0.4.4
jupyterlab-pygments      0.2.2
jupyterlab-widgets       3.0.7
jupyterthemes            0.20.0
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using JupyterLab in a JupyterHub instance and the other answers didn't work for me. I've solved the problem with a `<div>` around my image. Here is my 400px width and right aligned image:

```
<div style="max-width:400px;margin-left: auto; margin-right: 0;">
    ![My Image alt text](image.jpg)
</div>
```

Comment: Seems specific to JupyterLab, because in Jupyter notebook, this didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEh5s.png)

**change this 'Code' to 'Markdown' as like the screenshot. Later add**

```
<div> <img src="bar graph.png" alt="Drawing" style="width: 400px;"/></div>
```

**you are done**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).