# Is it possible to SCALE a pasted image in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, markdown

I can paste/drag&drop images into a jupyter notebook markdown cell. 
They will appear as follows:

```
![image.png](attachment:image.png)
```

The image is displayed correctly (but to large).
I am  however unable to scale them. I tried varius solutions from this question: [Changing image size in Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14675913/changing-image-size-in-markdown)

Unfortunately they all won't work for me. After pressing shift+Enter the cell just displays the entered text and the image is gone. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of today the accepted answer no longer works, the "proper" way of doing it is:

```
<div>
<img src="attachment:image.png" width="400">
</div>
```

But even this variant is not ideal as it doesn't export image when saving as to html. Votes here are welcome: https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/1057

Comment: would be useful to know which jupyter version you are running. For me your solution worked as well, so I assume it's the more general way. Also exporting to html worked for me in both solutions. I am running jupyter v.4.4.0

Comment: jupyter-core == 4.5.0

Answer (score 7):

Problem solved in this anwser:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49150804/5105118

```
<img src="attachment:image.png" width="400">
```

**EDIT**
to be more precise I will add a step-by-step

1. Copy your image (not the URL/path but i.e open in Paint and select region to copy, then press Ctrl+C)
2. go to notebook cell in math mode and paste image with Ctrl+V
3. something similar as the following should appear in your cell: `![image.png](attachment:image.png)`
4. **edit** this line to match `<img src="attachment:image.png" width="400px">` or apparently in newer jupyter versions (>4.4.0) surround them with `<div>` tags as noted in the answer from Antony Hatchkins: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58511216/5105118
5. somehow the pasted image is linked to the text *"attachment:image.png"* thus this part should not be touched while editing

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Would you please elaborate on how exactly this worked for you. If I replace `![image.png](attachment:image.png)` with `<img src="attachment:image.png" width="400">` the image disappears, but if I place both I see both images one above the other.

Comment: could you try editing the text instead of replacing?

Comment: I read the source code, I understand how it works, it really does not matter.

Answer (score 3):

In a markup cell copy an image, you then get something like this:

```
![afbeelding.png](attachment:afbeelding.png)
```

Then you may remove this line and copy this into the cell:

```
<div>
   <img src="attachment:afbeelding.png" width="300">
</div>
```

Then the image is scaled. The essence is that you first have to copy a real image into the markup cell. Depending on language, you always get the same text, but the image as soon as you execute the cell. Then replacing the text with the HTML text does the trick.
Nothing happens until you copied a real image into the cell, which given

Comment: Works fine in jupyter, but nbconvert doesn't accept it.

Answer (score 0):

you can also change the image witdh with css:

```html
%%html
<style>.inner_cell img{ width:450px; float:left }</style>
```