# How to resize image in Jupyter Notebook that is loaded from local file?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

How to resize the image in this code?

```
![italy.png](attachment:italy.png)
```

I tried according to this link but not working
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41598916/resize-the-image-in-jupyter-notebook-using-markdown)

Comment: You should try the `<img ...` method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57384504/19401) in the question you linked to.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resize the image in jupyter notebook using markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41598916/resize-the-image-in-jupyter-notebook-using-markdown)