# Changing the format of a screenshot in Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I can display screenshots in my notebook by just using the snipping tool and then pasting them in.

```
![image-3.png](attachment:image-3.png)
```

but if i want to format it, i keep getting broken links. Ive tried the following and not sure what is wrong with it:

```
<p>
<img src="C:\Users\mannf\Pictures\Screenshots\Screenshot 2023-12-13 103135.png" alt="Screenshot" style="width:600px;height:200px;border:2px solid black;border-radius:10px;">
</p>
```

or

```
<p>
<img src="image-4.png" alt="Image 4" style="width:600px;height:200px;">
</p>
```

[image: Screenshot of whats displayed when i run the above code.]

Comment: What if you remove the spaces from the file names/path?

Comment: Still got the same issue.

Comment: Did you try a simpler form like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77128402/8508004)? Does it work with the attachment version? Like so,  `<img src="attachment:Screenshot.png" width="500"/>`.  You seem to be mixing and matching sources of the images. For example, in your post text the top part before 'but if i want to format it,' doesn't match the lower part. Stick with **first** working out the upper approach and see if it works and then move to trying the other with a simpler file and path, placing the image next to the notebook. In other words, you are asking two questions, it seems.

Comment: Still didnt work, so i gave up on it for the moment. Thanks very much for your help though. Will update if i finally manage to get it working.