# Changing image size in Markdown on Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, image-resizing

I'm trying to post a picture to a file on my Gitlab using markdown

```
    ![](test/media/screenshot.png)
```

seems to work but is far too large.
Other solutions I've tried and don't seem to work are as follows:

```
    <img src="https://gitlab.com/example/screenshot" width="48">
    ![](test/media/screenshot.png =100x20)
    ![](test/media/screenshot.png =250x)
    <img src="https://gitlab.com/example/screenshot" alt="Drawing" style="width: 200px;"/>
```

Any ideas on what I can do rather than re-sizing every image I have?

Comment: Use the same approach with <img > as StackOverflow uses

Answer (score 231):

**Raw HTML works**
Try the following: after uploading your image, use **img** tag with src pointing to the path of uploaded image, for me it's working:
The following is from one of my files

```
![](/uploads/d19fcc3d3b4d313c8cd7960a343463b6/table.png)
<img src="/uploads/d19fcc3d3b4d313c8cd7960a343463b6/table.png"  width="120" height="120">
```

[image]

Check this link, where I've put different size of same image https://gitlab.com/Basel.issmail/resize-image/wikis/resizing-image

There is an issue on gitlab discuss [Add control over images with Markdown](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/21189)

Comment: Since this week, they add borders and padding to all `img` elements that are not emoji, which is highly annoying. Filed an issue [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/csslab/issues/64).

Comment: I wanted to show the thumbnail image with the possibility to download the original image. This works `[<img src="/uploads/9177bb9d710cdfd0288b9ce151e4bcb5/image.png" width="32" height="32">](/uploads/9177bb9d710cdfd0288b9ce151e4bcb5/image.png)` The downside is that gitlab shows the paperclip and border and while loading the image there is a blank box in the original size, but for my case thats sufficient.

Comment: Thanks. I've used only "img" tag and deleted the original markdown line. (first line abve "img") Solved my case. :+1:

Comment: For those who want to use the percentage: `<img src="image.png" width="50%" height="50%"` or `<img src="image.png"  style="height:75%; width:75%" >`

Comment: Using the style attribute doesn't have an effect (anymore?)

Comment: As @csonuryilmaz points out, I'm not why/if/when the markdown and the HTML is needed.

Comment: `style="..."` doesn't work, it's been sanitized: https://github.com/gjtorikian/html-pipeline/blob/v2.12.3/lib/html/pipeline/sanitization_filter.rb#L42

Comment: Following code give good result: ![]() <img src="/uploads/d19fcc3d3b4d313c8cd7960a343463b6/table.png"  width="120"> It shows a clickable thumbail with a fixed width (and keep ratio image).

Comment: This answer is more up-to-date, using a feature introduced in GitLab 15.7: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74906593/9778755

Answer (score 105):

[GitLab 15.7](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/12/22/gitlab-15-7-released/#change-the-dimensions-of-images-in-markdown) (December 2022) adds an official support for this:

> ### Change the dimensions of images in Markdown
>
> Before this release, there were no controls for changing the size
> of images rendered within Markdown text areas.
> This often led to unwieldy images with no control over how much space they took up in descriptions and comments.
>
> You can now set the width and height of how images are rendered directly
> in Markdown by appending the `{width=x height=y}` attributes to the image reference. Sizes can be specified with pixels or percentages.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/markdown.html#change-the-image-dimensions) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/28118).

Example:

```
![image](/uploads/cf5da4685999975fef9afd1aa43b9173/image.png){width=40%}
![image](/uploads/cf5da4685999975fef9afd1aa43b9173/image.png){height=250px}
```

Answer (score 11):

Following code give good result: (the URL set in  tag is the one generated by Gitlab when attaching a image)

`![]() <img src="/uploads/d19fcc3d3b4d313c8cd7960a343463b6/table.png"  width="120">`

It shows a clickable thumbail with a fixed width (and keep image ratio).