# How add height and width of the image in .md file

Tags: markdown, gatsby

Hi i am trying resize the image in a .md file for the following code

```
![unsplash.com](./photo-1490474418585-ba9bad8fd0ea.jpg)
```

I have tried the following approaches but didnt work

```
![unsplash.com](./photo-1490474418585-ba9bad8fd0ea.jpg){width: 200px}

![unsplash.com](./photo-1490474418585-ba9bad8fd0ea.jpg =200x200)
```

I want to resize the image to 200px. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing image size in Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14675913/changing-image-size-in-markdown)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to insert the HTML directly into the .md?

`<img src="http://....jpg" width="200" height="200" />`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot style the image directly, however, a workaround is to enclose your image in a div. You can then do most of the styling on this div (sizing and positioning) using either inline CSS or a class that you can reference on a global css. Make sure you also use the standard html `<img>` tag since the markdown inside the div will not be parsed:

```
<div class="blogimage" style="float:right;width:300px;padding:10px 0 10px 10px;">
    <img src="sampleimage.png"/>
</div>
```