# How to use Github buttons in Markdown (README.md)

Tags: javascript, html, github, markdown

I want to add buttons to my markdown that, when pressed, let the viewer **fork, star or watch** a github repository.

I already tried adding the html to my README.md, but it does not work.

Especially

```
<script async defer src="https://buttons.github.io/buttons.js></script>
```

does not seem to work (it just displays the link)

Is there a way to use Github Buttons (https://buttons.github.io) in a markdown (.md) file?

Or are there other ways to inplement this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems impossible to use *the unofficial* Github Buttons in a Markdown file.

However, you can use different links to access those actions (markdown style):

- Fork:

`[fork my repository](https://github.com/user/repository/fork)`

- Watch/ Follow:

`[watch this repo](https://github.com/user/repository/subscription)`

- Create Issues:

`[create issue](https://github.com/user/repository/issues/new)`

If somebody knows a link to **star a repo**, I will add that to this answer :)

Comment: AFAIK to star a project is needed a PUT, so it can't be done from a readme markdown: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/activity#star-a-repository-for-the-authenticated-user

Answer (score 8):

If you created an image file with the button you could incorporate it directly in markdown.

For example:

```
[![](https://s18955.pcdn.co/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/github.png)](https://github.com/user/repository/subscription)
```

To control the size of the button you may need to incorporate html borrowing from this answer [Changing image size in Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14675913/changing-image-size-in-markdown/60004801#60004801)

```
[<img src="https://s18955.pcdn.co/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/github.png" width="25"/>](https://github.com/user/repository/subscription)
```