# Resize Markdown image in flutter

Tags: flutter, markdown, readme

I need to resize a local image from the assets folder in my markdown file.

I currently have this image that does display in my .md file.

[image]

I need to resize the image to make it a bit smaller.

Is it possible with the current package?

Answer (score 0):

You can use inline HTML `<img/>` with providing size.

```markdown
<img src = "assets/images/image01.png" width="x" height="x" />
```

Or

```markdown
[<img src ="assets/images/image01.png" width="100" height="x"/> ](assets/images/image01.png)
```

More and ref: [Changing image size in Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14675913/10157127)

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="drawing.jpg" alt="drawing" width="200"/>
```

This the github discussion on this, https://gist.github.com/uupaa/f77d2bcf4dc7a294d109

Answer (score 0):

When considering specifically the [Flutter Markdown plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_markdown), a good way to resize images is to make use of the `imageBuilder` parameter.

For your example, here is the code that would resize the image when returning the `Markdown` Widget:

```dart
imageBuilder: (uri, title, alt) {
  return Image.asset(uri.path,width: 50,height: 50,);
},
```

For other cases such as network images for example, you can find inspiration from the default function called, `kDefaultImageBuilder` when no `imageBuilder` is specified: https://github.com/flutter/packages/blob/ec4a54604ff5043891bae98498116a714061baa5/packages/flutter_markdown/lib/src/_functions_io.dart#L18-L42