# Rmarkdown: image at bottom of title page

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am creating a title sheet for a pdf document in Rmarkdown. I would like to be able to put the image line.png at the bottom of the title page.

Please can someone help me with this. The code I have used thus far is as follows:

```
---
title: "Some title"
author: "Prepared by: Anon"
date: '`r paste("Date:",Sys.Date())`'
output: pdf_document
---

\pagenumbering{gobble} 

\centerline{\includegraphics[height=3in]{picture_folder/line.png}}

\clearpage
```

Answer (score 0):

RMarkDown is a tool that allow you to rapidly sketch a neat and tidy text with embedded data. I possess books written with RMD, and I even wrote a couple of article myself! In any case, to proper use its full potential, and finely manage images and more personal settings, it is quite common to embed HTML code in RMD. Your question is beautifully answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255170/markdown-and-image-alignment), and reports as example:

```
<img style="float: bottom;" src="yourimage.jpg">

Continue your RMD document
```

If you need a quick HTML reference for images management, I suggest you to consult [this](http://ccm.net/contents/249-managing-images-in-html) page. It is short and precise. It should help you to solve the most common problems with images alignment.

Comment: Hi Worice, thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work for me; the image does not appear at all

Comment: Did you try to modify the path of the image?