# Inline CSS in Markdown

Tags: html, css, markdown

I'm using Simplemde ( markdown editor ) as an embdedded textarea for writing articles in my website. I've recently encountered a problem :

While writing, if I insert an image , it stretches to 100%, taking over the entire page, like this :

[image]

I tried inserting inline css (style tags) in the textarea, but that didn't work.

However in the preview option, I used inline css (set height and width at 400px ) and it worked :

[image]

How can I set the image size as per my preference in this markdown editor ?

UPDATE : I already tried embedding HTML in Markdown ,like :

```
<img style="width:400px;" src="abc.jpg">
```

But this doesn't seem to work, and my the image doesn't even appear in the article this way. The entire img tag gets shrinked to `<img>` in my textarea!

Comment: share relevant code please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be able to answer your question, it looks like you can embed HTML in markdown and you can add styles that way. [Markdown and image alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255170/markdown-and-image-alignment)

You said you tried inline, did you try just HTML? 
[image]

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/geBaa.png" width="50">
```

Comment: Actually I did, see my updated question. Don't know why textarea is behaving this way! it's not even accepting the image tag

Comment: Hmm, can you provide your markdown? Also, do you have a link to your website?

Comment: Okay, I just decided to go with my intuition, and it was a package(express-sanitizer). I installed it so that no one can write a script tag and only HTML will be rendered. I commented it out and it started working just fine! Thanks anyway, Squeakasaur !

Comment: Actually, I had one more question (doesn't really deserve to be asked seperately), I have a form where the author writes a post in parts, one input box for title,one for image, one for textarea! Sice, input has a type of text, is there any way I can use italic/bold tags for title , just as in textarea ?

Comment: HTML/CSS , but typing text in input will result in the exact input. Ex : 
<em>Your Name</em> will result in <em>Your Name</em>

Comment: Yes you can style these but are you asking like when they submit the form to have it keep the styling?

You can style inputs like this:
input[type=text]{
 font-size: 10px;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-style: italic;
}

Comment: But the problem arises, when I only want to style a part of the text (ex : name of a movie) .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139048/discussion-between-squeakasaur-and-eknoor4197).

Answer (score 10):

Embedding CSS in Markdown is easy. It may depend on the markdown parser but usually one can include any valid HTML and CSS in markdown files.

```
<style type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
* { color: red; }
</style>
This is a markdown file. Save this snipped under `test.md` and convert into html5
with `pandoc` or any other markdown parser.
```

A very powerful markdown parser is `pandoc`!

```
pandoc --from=markdown --to=html5 --output=test.html test.md
```