# how to add style of url image in markdown in React

Tags: markdown

Help me out to style the Url image in markdown in React

```
 ![ChangeLogApp](Link) 



I want to add styling to url image in markdown .. please tell me how it is possible. I have tried alot of things but in vain
```

Comment: https://www.xaprb.com/blog/how-to-style-images-with-markdown/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inline CSS in Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43019748/inline-css-in-markdown)

Comment: issue not resolved

Comment: @Muzamilijaz question/comment does not parse ;-) see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask