# Jupyter Notebook position embedded image in markdown

Tags: python, html, image, jupyter-notebook

I drag and drop an image in Jupyter Notebook. By default it gives me a code:

```
![myimage.png](attachment:myimage.png)
```

Can I do something to above to align it right "**WITHOUT**" `<img ..>`?

Comment: This is possibly a duplicate of [Markdown and image alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255170/markdown-and-image-alignment).

Comment: @CypherX read the question please. I have explicitly asked "WITHOUT" the use of `<img...>`

Comment: You could use CSS as suggested here: https://msudol.com/how-to-align-images-in-markdown-without-html-or-extensions/

Comment: @Alex thats same as using <img> I am curious can we do it without that. This is not an easy answer I am afraid. I have been looking for an answer for few hours now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [github README.md center image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090472/github-readme-md-center-image)

Comment: As seen in [github README.md center image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090472/github-readme-md-center-image): "The Markdown syntax doesn't provide one with the ability to control the position of an image."

Comment: @Alex you are right. Please post the answer. I can then accept it.

Answer (score 4):

You can embed an image in markdown as follows. See other suggestions made here [Markdown and image alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255170/markdown-and-image-alignment)

```
<img style="float: right;" src="myimage.png">
```

Or,

```
![image alt >](/image-right.jpg)
![image alt <](/image-left.jpg)
![image alt ><](/center-image.jpg)
```

## Advanced Example:

I will share here one of the modifications I made for my jupyter notebooks markdown content. I hope this will be helpful.

```html
<div style="width:image width px; 
            font-size:80%; 
            text-align:center; 
            float: right; padding-left-right-top-bottom:0.5em;  
            border-style: solid; border-color: rgba(211, 211, 211, 0.1);
            background-color: rgba(0, 250, 250, 0.1);">
    <img src="./Resources/Markdown/898px-Row_and_column_major_order.svg.png" 
         alt="alternate text" 
         width=200 
         style="padding-bottom:0.5em;"/>
    <div style="padding: 3px; 
                width: 200px; 
                word-wrap: break-word; 
                text-align:justify;">
        Illustration of difference between row- and column-major ordering. <br> 
        <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Row_and_column_major_order.svg" 
           style="float: right;"> 
           Image Source 
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Output

[image]

Note: This is possibly a duplicate of [Markdown and image alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255170/markdown-and-image-alignment).

Comment: @Varun Please check the [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255170/markdown-and-image-alignment) I shared. It has multiple solutions to embedding an image using markdown and aligning the image.

Comment: you need to understand why and what I am doing. I am embedding an image so it's not lost when I send a notebook. Otherwise I need to send the image along with the notebook and hope the the receiver downloads the image along with notebook.

Comment: @Varun I see. Now I understand your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve this problem, for me it works well but has disadvantage:

1. When we drag and drop an image in Jupyter Notebook, the image was saved as a base64 str inside a html img element. It is the way jupyter notebook attach and save an image. Your can inspect this element in the jupyter notebook page by open the devtool of the browser.
2. You can just copy this element from devtool of the browser and paste it in the markdown cell in your jupyter notebook. Then you can adjust the alignment of this element easily and meanwhile the image has been attached to your notebook.

Disadvantage is: you have a very long markdown cell in your notebook because normally the base64 str for the image is long.