# How to format images with markdown, Sphinx latexpdf

Tags: pdf, markdown, python-sphinx

I have a markdown document that I wish to output in pdf format. I cannot find a way to format the images correctly.

If I use

```
<center><img src="_images/parameter_form.png" alt="Select Parameters" width="400"></center>
```

I works perfectly with *make html*, but with *make latexpdf* the image does not appear at all.

If I use (based on [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255170/markdown-and-image-alignment#answer-5054055))

```
![Select Parameters](_images/parameter_form.png) { width=400 }
```

The images is not sized  and the format string *{ width=400 }* appears in the text

What am I doing wrcng?

Comment: You are trying to use HTML in a PDF. That will not work. There might be some Markdown flavor that does what you want, but I do not know what that could be. Otherwise you must find a syntax that supports image sizing, such as MyST or reStructuredText.

Comment: The second example I my code is markdown, but as you say doesnt support sizing. I think I'll abandon pdf and just provide an html doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to use [MyST](https://myst-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). This Sphinx parser allows a richer syntax in markdown and specifically the *image* tag

````
```{image} _images/parameter_form.png
:alt: Select Parameters
:width: 400px
:align: center
```
````

Perfect!