# How to set max-width on image in GitHub markdown?

Tags: github-flavored-markdown

I want to embed an image in to my `README.md` markdown document on GitHub, but I want it to be responsive, so I decided I want it to behave like `max-width`.

I tried doing:

```html
<div align="center">
  <img src="./logo.svg" style="max-width: 24em">
</div>
```

But when I put it on GitHub it doesn't respect my `max-width: 24em`. In fact, when I inspect the element in the browser devtools, I see that it resolves to `max-width: 100%`!

So how do I do this proper?

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that GitHuB sanitizes the markup before rendering it, and in your case removes the inline style. (See [this reference on GitHuB Markup readme](https://github.com/github/markup#github-markup) for what happens.)

Instead, one option is to use the width attribute. For example:

```
<img src="./logo.svg" width="24em">
```

Of course, what you are looking for is a max-width so you can make it responsive, not simply width. If that is truly necessary, then you may be to do it with CSS. (As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255170/markdown-and-image-alignment#answer-5054055).) In this case embed the image using normal markdown syntax:

```
![logo](logo.svg)
```

And then have in a custom CSS file with:

```
img[alt=logo] { max-width: 24em; }
```

A possible option (but no guarantees on this), since your image is an SVG, is to embed the CSS directly within it using the `<foreignObject>` tag. Or you could use a different SVG for this purpose. This gets your custom CSS available for use by the readme. [Here's an article that explains how to do this](https://dev.to/sergix/add-css-to-your-github-readmes-gf8). If you can do it all in the same SVG, all the better.